# Print loop output in one line vector in R

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I want to print the output as a one line for each variable dd and vv

```
df=c(1:20)
df=matrix(df,ncol = 5,nrow = 4, byrow = T)
x=c(1.5,7.5,12.5,19.5)
for (j in 1:4) {
  for (i in 1:4) {
    if( sum(df[j,i],df[j,i+1])/2 ==x[j])
    {xx=c(df[j,i],df[j,i+1]) }
  }
  dd=as.vector((df[j,i+1]-df[j,i])/6)
  vv=as.vector(xx)
  print(c(vv,dd))
}
```

I got the following

```
  [1] 1.0000000 2.0000000 0.1666667
  [1] 7.0000000 8.0000000 0.1666667
  [1] 12.0000000 13.0000000  0.1666667
  [1] 19.0000000 20.0000000  0.1666667
```

and what I want to print from my code is

```
[1]  1  2  7  8 12 13 19 20
```

and

```
[1]0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The situation here is that the print statement is inside of the for loop and did not store your results as a vector that appends all the answers (instead, your code stores each result as a unique variable for each iteration). I see the previous answers, but here is my modification which is very similar to your original.

1) Added two NULL vectors, dd and vv

2) Stored each looped result into the respective vectors

3) Print statement outside of the for loop

```
dd <- NULL
vv <- NULL


df=c(1:20)
df=matrix(df,ncol = 5,nrow = 4, byrow = T)
x=c(1.5,7.5,12.5,19.5)
for (j in 1:4) {
  for (i in 1:4) {
    if( sum(df[j,i],df[j,i+1])/2 ==x[j])
    {xx=c(df[j,i],df[j,i+1]) }
  }
  dd <- as.vector(c(dd,(df[j,i+1]-df[j,i])/6))
  vv <- as.vector(c(vv,(xx)))
}

print(dd)
print(vv)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way by storing the results in a vector:

```
# store the results
dd_var = c()
vv_var = c()

for (j in 1:4) {
  for (i in 1:4) {
    if( sum(df[j,i],df[j,i+1])/2 ==x[j])
    {xx=c(df[j,i],df[j,i+1]) }
  }

  dd=as.vector((df[j,i+1]-df[j,i])/6)
  vv=as.vector(xx)
  dd_var = append(dd_var, dd)
  vv_var = append(vv_var, vv)
}

cat(dd_var,'\t')
0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 

cat(vv_var, '\t')
1 2 7 8 12 13 19 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Pretty similar what @YOLO came up with... Store the result into an object and print it using `cat`. There are other ways of going about this.

```
dd.out <- c()
vv.out <- c()

for (j in 1:4) {
  for (i in 1:4) {
    if( sum(df[j,i],df[j,i+1])/2 ==x[j])
    {xx=c(df[j,i],df[j,i+1]) }
  }

  dd=as.vector((df[j,i+1]-df[j,i])/6)
  vv=as.vector(xx)

  # Growing an object is not optimal, but works.
  dd.out <- c(dd.out, dd)
  vv.out <- c(vv.out, vv)
}
cat(vv.out, "\n", dd.out)

1 2 7 8 12 13 19 20 
 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667 0.1666667
```